# How to assert multiple changes to web elements in one test

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, coded-ui-tests

**How do you assert that multiple changes have occurred on a page after an event?**

Example of behaviour I'd like to assert:

1. click some button
2. the main menu collapses
3. some other elements appear.

I would like to assert that all those things have happened after I clicked the button. Do I really have to write identical methods with each asserting on each one of those changes?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to write more methods for each assert? You can just have a method that checks whether the element is visible and call it once for each element.

```
private boolean IsElementVisible(By by)
{
    try
    {
        return driver.FindElement(by).IsDisplayed();
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

private List<By> VerifyElementVisibility(
          List<By> expectedVisibile, List<By> expectedInvisible)
{
    List<By> failedExpectations = new List<By>();

    for (By by in expectedVisible)
    {
        if(!IsElementVisible(by)
        {
            failedExpectations.Add(by);
        }
    }

    for (By by in expectedInvisible)
    {
        if(IsElementVisible(by)
        {
            failedExpectations.Add(by);
        }
    }
    return failedExpectations;
}
List<By> failedExpectations = VerifyElementVisiblity(visibleElements, invisibleElements);
Assert.IsTrue(failedExpectations.Count == 0,
     failedExpectations.Count.ToString() + " elements did not meet expectations");
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: there's a problem with the answer - In case the first element (by1) is not visible this will fail the test without cheking the second element..

Comment: If the first element is not visible, then IsElementVisible would return false, which would indeed fail the first Assert, but it would still continue on to the second Assert, no? This may be outside of the scope of this discussion, but I thought that multiple Asserts were acceptable (although maybe not desirable). I was under the impression that if the first Assert fails, Asserts that follow it would still get checked.

Comment: @user3780751 No, barakcaf is right. I can throw something together that would work for any number of elements failing but it gets ugly when you want some to appear and some to not.

Comment: @user3780751 I changed it up. This will check all of the ones that fail in store it in the `failedExpectations` list. I personally still prefer the multiple assert method to this, but you might like this more. To view which ones failed you'll need to debug and look at the contents of failedExpectations. There might be a way to turn the `By`s into a readable string but I couldn't find it.